# What is the syntax for comments in Zend Frameworks application.ini?

Tags: php, zend-framework, syntax

I'd like to comment some lines in my Zend `application.ini` file.

Is it possible to comment lines?  What is the syntax?

I simply could not find an answer.

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/INI_file

Comment: http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

Comment: [Support for prefixing comments with # in INI files has been removed](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) in PHP 7. This applies to  parse_ini_file() and parse_ini_string() methods as well. Better to stick with ;

Comment: @nawfal good catch, although nobody is suggesting to use # characters :-) The semicolon (;) character is and was the official character for comments. Across languages.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's a general `ini` format that comment lines begin with `;`

```
; this is a comment
foo = bar
```

Answer (score 6):

start the line with a semi-colon.

```
; This is a comment
[section]
key=value
```

Answer (score 3):

Comments in PHP ini files (which I believe Zend makes use of) start with a ;

Answer (score 0):

Semicolons (;) at the beginning of the line indicate a comment in ini file.

Answer (score 0):

;(semicolon) in any .ini file..